# Trying to make a .desktop file that runs a .py file

Tags: 14.04, executable, .desktop

I created a .desktop file that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = My Script
Comment = Test
Exec= /home/zito/Documents/loc_tk.py
Icon=
Terminal=false
type=Application
```

I put the hashbang in the python file `#!/usr/bin/env python`
and I also set the python file to be executable but every time I double click my `.desktop` file it brings up the error "There was an error launching the application".

Comment: Replace with `Exec= /home/zito/Documents/python3 loc_tk.py`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is a small thing...

A desktop file's keyword should *always* start with a capital, so in this case it is:

```
Type=Application (Type instead of type)
```

it is not necessary to use `python` in front of the `/path/to/script` section in the in the `Exec=` line, *IF* you made it executable *AND* you have the shebang in your script

**Note**

if you run your desktop file on your desktop, you should make the desktop file executable as well!

Comment: Thanks that actually fixed by problem it was just a dumb typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name = My Script
Comment = Test
Exec= /home/zito/Documents/python loc_tk.py
Icon=
Terminal=false
type=Application
```